# Quasar Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

(node:21216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:   Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'

- loader.js:815 Function.Module._resolveFilename
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15
- loader.js:667 Function.Module._load
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27
- loader.js:887 Module.require
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19
- helpers.js:74 require
  internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18
- typeof.js:3 Object.
  [front]/[mini-css-extract-plugin]/[ajv-keywords]/dist/definitions/typeof.js:3:19
- loader.js:999 Module._compile
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30
- loader.js:1027 Object.Module._extensions..js
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10
- loader.js:863 Module.load
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32
- loader.js:708 Function.Module._load
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14
- loader.js:887 Module.require
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19

(node:21216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The problem seems to be in mini-css-extract-plugin somewhere between version 2.4.3 and 2.4.5. Reverting mini-css-extract-plugin to 2.4.2 fixes it for now.

npm i mini-css-extract-plugin@2.4.2 --save-exact

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had the same issue when I used JHipster, which I solved by running this command

```
npm install --save-dev ajv@^7
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14492#issuecomment-810548947)

Comment: Make sure to `npm list ajv` to know which version you need. For me it was `npm install --save-dev ajv@8 `

Answer (score 10):

I found that my `package-lock.json` file was imposing constraints that meant npm couldn't sort things out.

Firstly, I used `npm ls ajv` very helpful in illustrating where the dependencies were coming from (thanks @Greg Trevellick).

The solution for me, possibly a little drastic, was to remove the `package-lock.json` file and the `node_modules` directory and reinstall.

```
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 6):

I just hit the same error several times recently. In my case the error was based on `ajv-keywords` and `ajv-formats` plugin incompatibility with `node js 8 and 12` (legacy project).

To analyse the problem, you can always use the `npm ls ajv` command, to see, which module try to use something incompatible.

Personally, I spent days to figure out the right combination for `ajv schema`, `node` and `ajv plugins` to make them  work together properly.
(In my case, I used `ajv 6.4.x`, what I had to downgrade to 6.12, then I used `ajv-keywords@3.5.1` and `ajv-formats@1.5.1` which I had to dowgnrade to `3.0` and `1.4`)

Comment: `npm ls ajv` helpeed me - pointed me towards adding a specific version of `ajv` to my package.json

Answer (score 2):

This recently occurred for me and I have `legacy-peer-deps=true` in my `.npmrc` file and I removed that and deleted my node_modules and package-lock.json and it all worked after that

Answer (score 0):

Add "ajv": "^7" in package.json. Will work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHDLZ.png)